# How to change the voltage on a FLSUN QQ

Tags: delta, flsun-qq, power-supply

I just bought a FLSUN QQ and the instructions say I need to change the voltage from 220 to 110. Sadly the instructions don't say how to do that. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: What is your problem? some power source has an auto detect to switch from 220v to 110v.

Comment: please attach a photo - that will help to help you

Comment: @profesor79 what would you like a photo of?

Comment: the best will be the psu label

Comment: @linuxdan the psu is the power source, is the part that is connected to the wall socket. may be is inside the bottom of your printer.

Comment: I took some pictures last night of the components near the plug, but the main one I got decent pictures of was the power board for the heated bed. Will try again tonight. After researching online, it seems like I'm looking for a big metal box similar to a desktop computer power supply...

Comment: @Linuxdan Are you saying you had to unscrew the bottom to get to the switch? I have a Sunlu and the manual is horrible. I thought this was a switch to push in to move left to right.![picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYIaM.jpg)![picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGvdw.jpg)![picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuLgA.jpg)

Comment: @DannyBlaq yes, the switch in this case was on the side of the PSU which is in the base of the printer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if this is the case with all FLSUN QQ printers, but mine was indeed set to 220v as the instructions/user manual indicated. First I needed to remove the bottom of the printer. Then there was a switch on the side of the power supply with the following label:

[image: voltage switch label]

I know the picture is terrible, but the lighting inside the base of the printer was less than optimal. It should be pretty easy to find once you know what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks to @professor79 and  Fernando Baltazar for their comments that got me looking in the right place.

Comment: Very nice to come back and answer your own question. Please accept your own answer after the waiting period. From Help Center: "You can also accept your own answer, but you must wait 48 hours to do so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem!" I doubt there will be a better answer as you investigated yourself.

Comment: @linuxdan well done!, mostly power supply has this kind of switch.

Comment: My FLSUN QQ 2020 was exactly what linduxdan said, except it was 115v / 230v printed on the power supply. Thanks!